# How to properly step by step install java and javafx in Intellij on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, sdk

I think I am not alone who doesn't know how to properly download Java and JavaFX on Linux. And how make it works in IntelliJ Idea 
So my questions are:

1. I'm looking for Java JRE or Java SDK?
2. Must Java and JavaFX be at same version?
3. How I will connect it with IntelliJ
4. Do I have to write something like in windows "path variable"?

Maybe this is not proper question, because it was answered somewhere else, but I dont undrestand basic things about installation of Java. 
 Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) JRE is a Java Runtime Environment - enough for Java code to run but not enough to develop code. What you need is JDK (Java Development Kit), you can download it here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

2) No, they don't need to be the same version

3) Follow these steps: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven
I prefer doing it with Maven (less hassle) but you can find easy to follow explanations for both on that page

4)Yes in linux you need to add Path variable as well - here are the instructions: 
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable

Comment: Doesn't the package manager automatically set up the path correctly. At least when I was installing openjdk at work it did...